# Regular 503 error every 5 minutes for logged in users

Tags: errors

I am getting regular 503 errors (every 5 minutes) on my wordpress site for all logged in users including myself as the administrator, which has been happening over the last few weeks. I have had many hours on the phone across different days with GoDaddy who have had their backend team run numerous tests and tried to diagnose the issue. They believe that the server is running fine (my other site is on the same server and experiencing no issues). They believe it to be a theme or plugin issue but having deactivated all plugins and changed themes, the issue persists.

Again this issue is only experienced by logged in users, 5 minutes after logging in. Waiting a few minutes (sometimes resolves issue) OR accessing the homepage from another browser (not logged in) always makes the error disappear until the next 5 minutes are up.

It feels like there is some cyclic process eating up the resources perhaps by a plugin (which continues even after deactivation) and as it only affects logged in users if seems it may relate to a database connection issue?!

I am at such a loss and would welcome any help / ideas on trying to resolve this issue.

Below is a log of my attempt to work out any possible pattern:

```
Logging started at 12.37 GMT
All Plugins Disabled
Spacious Theme Active
Logged in and refreshing dashboard page every 3 seconds (using a chrome auto refresh addon):
12.39 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)
12.45 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)
12.50 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)

12.50 Theme changed to AWADA (plugins still all deactivated)
Logged in and refreshing dashboard page every 3 seconds (using a chrome auto refresh addon):
12.56 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)

12.57 Theme changed to HappenStance (plugins still all deactivated)
Logged in and refreshing dashboard page every 3 seconds (using a chrome auto refresh addon):
13.01 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)

13.01 Theme changed back to Spacious (plugins still all deactivated)
Logged in and refreshing dashboard page every 3 seconds (using a chrome auto refresh addon):
13.06 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)
13.12 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)
13.17 - 503 error (error remains until I load homepage from another browser where I am not logged in)


Conclusion - This error occurs after 5 minutes and remains for the logged in user until the site is accessed by another - which seems to reset the issue.
All plugins were disabled and various themes used with the error continuing on a timed basis - plugins and themes therefore don't seem to be to blame.
```

PLEASE HELP

EDIT:
These are the plugins the site uses:

Advanced Cron Manager

Akismet Anti-Spam

Contact Form 7

Download Manager

File Manager

Google XML Sitemap Generator

Hide Admin Bar From Non-admins

Import Users from CSV

Login With Ajax

Modal Window (free version)

Paid Memberships Pro

Paid Memberships Pro - Add PayPal Express Add On

Paid Memberships Pro - Import Users from CSV Add On

Qwizcards - online quizzes and flashcards

Search Engine Visibility

Sliced Invoices

Sliced Invoices & Contact Form 7

SOGO Add Script Header Footer

Testimonials Widget

WooCommerce

WooCommerce Checkout Manager

WooCommerce Helper

WooCommerce PDF WatermarkWooCommerce Stripe Gateway

Wordfence Security

WordPress User Notes

WP Bouncer

WP Full Stripe Free

WP-Pro-Quiz

WPDM - Button Template

WPDM - Image Button

WPDM - PDF Stamper

Yoast SEO

Comment: What plugins are you using?

Comment: Have edited post to include plugins

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you had far, far too many plugins. Disable everything, choose one of the `twenty****` default themes and try again.

You should also check your server log and see if you can see anything in there that would help (and post it here).

Lastly, take a backup of your entire site (code, uploads, database) and then do a clean install of the latest Wordpress release with a clean database and see if you still get an issue. It could still be a problem with your hosting or some configuration on your account.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All plugins had been disabled before i posted and when trouble shooting i have tested with a range of different themes including twenty****. I will try to post a server log and attempt clean install. Site was fine with all of these plugins active for months. Seems strange for this issue to have suddenly appeared.